# Angular 6 - page getting reloaded repeatedly while using window.location.reload()

Tags: angular6

I am working on Angular 6, i need to reload the same route url when ever the user hit home page. I tried using window.location.reload() in ngOnit, but the screen getting reloading repeatedly. I want to reload the home page for only once.

Comment: Sounds like you have a route config issue.  Can you post your route config and what url you are trying to reload?

Comment: const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
    //{ path: 'login', loadChildren : './login/login.module#LoginModule'},
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' },
    { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'},